# Creating an IReadOnlyList<string>

Tags: c#

How do I create an `IReadOnlyList<string>` with some values in it?

I found an example of `ReadOnlyCollection` which seems to convert an existing collection to an `ReadOnlyCollection` but that approach didn't work.

Here's what I tried:

```
var myList = new List<string>()
{
   "Hello World!",
   "Some more text here"
};

var myReadOnlyList = new IReadOnlyList<string>(myList);
```

I also tried adding my string values into an `IReadOnlyList<string>` during declaration but that didn't work either.

What's the right way to create a `IReadOnlyList<string>()` with some values in it?

Comment: `IReadOnlyList<string> myReadOnlyList = myList;` You cannot construct interfaces. The `List<>` implemented `IReadOnlyList<>`.

Comment: It's an interface.  You don't create instances of it directly.

Comment: `var readOnlyList = myList.AsReadOnly();` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you all! @RandRandom could you post this as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks again

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`IReadOnlyList<string>`, despite the name, just means "list you can read", it doesn't mean "immutable list". Whether the list is immutable depends on the concrete class that will end up implementing the interface.

Therefore, what you should do depends on your needs.

1. `IReadOnlyList<string> myReadOnlyList = myList;`. This works because [`List<string>` implements `IReadOnlyList<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). It does not prevent others from casting `myReadOnlyList` back to `List<string>`.
2. `IReadOnlyList<string> myReadOnlyList = myList.AsReadOnly();`. This creates a read-only proxy for the original list. Although it does prevent others from casting `myReadOnlyList` back to `List<string>`, the contents of `myReadOnlyList` may still change as a result of modifications on `myList`.
3. `IReadOnlyList<string> myReadOnlyList = ImmutableList.CreateRange(myList);` This creates an [`ImmutableList<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.111).aspx) which contains copies of the original list's contents and does not allow any modification. Changes to `myList` won't be visible in `myReadOnlyList`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
List<string> listData = new List<string>();
public IReadOnlyList<string> readOnlyData = listData.AsReadOnly();
```

And here's an example on how to use it:

```
string text = readOnlyData[0];
```

Note: Make sure that you add to `listData` before you assign it to `readOnlyData`.