# Is it better to use IEnumerable as read only list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ienumerable

I am downloading `.tgz` file from the remote server to a folder locally and then unzipping it out. After that I read all those `json/txt` files in memory. Below is my code which does that:

```
public IEnumerable<DataHolder> GetFiles(string fileName)
{
    // this will download files to a directory
    var isDownloadSuccess = DownloadFiles(_url, fileName, _directoryToDownload);
    if (!isDownloadSuccess.Result) { yield return default; }

    // this will unzip files in same directory
    var isUnzipSuccess = UnzipTgzFile(_directoryToDownload, fileName);
    if (!isUnzipSuccess) { yield return default; }

    // this will get list of all files in same directory
    IList<string> files = GetListOfFiles(_directoryToDownload);
    if (files == null || files.Count == 0) { yield return default; }

    // total files will be 500 max
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
    {
        var cfgPath = files[i];
        if (!File.Exists(cfgPath)) { continue; }
        var fileDate = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(cfgPath);
        var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(cfgPath);
        var pathPieces = cfgPath.Split(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var fileName = pathPieces[pathPieces.Length - 1];
        var md5Hash = CheckMD5(cfgPath);
        yield return new DataHolder
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            FileDate = fileDate,
            FileContent = fileContent,
            FileMD5HashValue = md5Hash
        };
    }
}
```

**Use Case:**

- If I am not able to download files successfully (`isDownloadSuccess` is false) then I want to return empty IEnumerable back.
- If I am not able to unzip files successfully (`isUnzipSuccess` is false) then I want to return empty IEnumerable back as well.
- If I am not able to get list of files successfully (`files`  list is empty) then I want to return empty IEnumerable back as well.
- If I had some processing issues in the for loop then I want to return empty IEnumerable back as well.
- Otherwise just return readonly IEnumerable back to the caller with data in it.

Problem I am having with above approach is - I cannot do empty check in the cases when it returns `yield return default` and also I am confuse on what happens if processing fails in for loop, will it return empty `IEnumerable` as well back to the caller?

```
IEnumerable<DataHolder> dataHolders = GetFiles(fileName);
// below  check doesn't work on negative cases
if (dataHolders == null || !dataHolders.Any())
    return false;

//....
```

So is this the right way to use `IEnumerable` here or I can use any other data structure which can provide **read only list** to the caller along with empty list (for negative cases) which I can easily check for null or empty.

**Question:**

My goal is just to return `read only list` back to the user with data in it (for positive cases). And for all negative cases, I need to return back empty read only list to the user.

Comment: `yield return default` [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63312940/11683) return an empty enumerable, nor does it stop enumeration of the enumerable that it returns. An empty enumerable is not the same as a null reference either. You need to decide which one you actually need.

Comment: yeah I just need to return read only list back to the user with data in it (for positive cases). And for all negative cases, I need to return back empty read only list to the user.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `yield` semantics here?

Comment: @Andy I am very new to C# like a month old so started reading about it and realized IEnumerable is read only so went with that. If there is any better way to rewrite above method then I am willing to learn that as well.

Comment: I would drop the `yield` and just return an `IReadOnlyList`

Comment: @Andy Can you provide an example with `IReadOnlyList` for my method if possible? It will help me to understand better on how to use this properly as well.

Comment: So you would create a `List<DataHolder>` in your method and simply populate it.. then when you return do this: `return myList.AsReadOnly();` Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49115272/1204153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We talked in chat, but will reiterate.

Yield doesn't really work here as we don't really need those semantics for any specific reason. You want to get a list of files to use later for comparing against other lists of files (they all have to be read in to memory eventually, may as well do it now):

```
public IReadOnlyList<DataHolder> GetFiles(string fileName)
{
    // this will download files to a directory
    var isDownloadSuccess = DownloadFiles(_url, fileName, _directoryToDownload);
    if (!isDownloadSuccess.Result) { return Array.Empty<DataHolder>(); }

    // this will unzip files in same directory
    var isUnzipSuccess = UnzipTgzFile(_directoryToDownload, fileName);
    if (!isUnzipSuccess) { return Array.Empty<DataHolder>(); }

    // this will get list of all files in same directory
    IList<string> files = GetListOfFiles(_directoryToDownload);
    if (files == null || files.Count == 0) { return Array.Empty<DataHolder>(); }

    var lst = new List<DataHolder>(files.Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
    {
        var cfgPath = files[i];
        if (!File.Exists(cfgPath)) { continue; }
        var fileDate = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(cfgPath);
        var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(cfgPath);
        var pathPieces = cfgPath.Split(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var fileName = pathPieces[pathPieces.Length - 1];
        var md5Hash = CheckMD5(cfgPath);
        lst.Add(new DataHolder
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            FileDate = fileDate,
            FileContent = fileContent,
            FileMD5HashValue = md5Hash
        });
    }
    return lst.AsReadOnly();
}
```

We are now just returning a read-only list of all your items, which allows you to do checks if any items exist, such as:

```
if(lst?.Count > 0){ /* There are items to process */ }
```

Also, this doesn't break your pattern as `IReadOnlyList` implements `IEnumerable`, so it will fit in quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Since you download and unzip all files at once, I understand that you're not concerned about this implementation being an actual iteratable (as a `foreach` would wait until everything is done before being able to iterate).
Keeping that in mind, the easiest you can do is to get rid of `yields` and return arrays.

Sample implementation (might need some spell check):

```
public IEnumerable<DataHolder> GetFiles(string fileName)
{
    // this will download files to a directory
    var isDownloadSuccess = DownloadFiles(_url, fileName, _directoryToDownload);
    if (!isDownloadSuccess.Result) { return Array.Empty<DataHolder>(); }

    // this will unzip files in same directory
    var isUnzipSuccess = UnzipTgzFile(_directoryToDownload, fileName);
    if (!isUnzipSuccess) { return Array.Empty<DataHolder>(); }

    // this will get list of all files in same directory
    IList<string> files = GetListOfFiles(_directoryToDownload);
    if (files == null || files.Count == 0) { return Array.Empty<DataHolder>(); }

    var data = new DataHolder[files.Count];

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            var cfgPath = files[i];
            if (!File.Exists(cfgPath)) { continue; }
            var fileDate = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(cfgPath);
            var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(cfgPath);
            var pathPieces = cfgPath.Split(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var fileName = pathPieces[pathPieces.Length - 1];
            var md5Hash = CheckMD5(cfgPath);

            data[i] = new DataHolder
            {
                FileName = fileName,
                FileDate = fileDate,
                FileContent = fileContent,
                FileMD5HashValue = md5Hash
            };
        }

        return data;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Array.Empty<DataHolder>();
    }
}
```

For consuming this, you would, for example:

```
var files = GetFiles("somename.txt");
if (!files.Any()) // do not check for files being null
{
    return;
}
```

Side note, I would change the first few lines into this, so you don't do sync-over-async which can cause deadlocks:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<DataHolder>> GetFiles(string fileName)
{
    // this will download files to a directory
    var isDownloadSuccess = await DownloadFiles(_url, fileName, _directoryToDownload);
    if (!isDownloadSuccess) { return Array.Empty<DataHolder>(); }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I stole your capacity thing and your Array.Empty thing :) Thanks for contributing in chat. Nice talking

Comment: question on last suggestion. My download method signature is like this - `public async Task<bool> DownloadFiles`. Is this also wrong in any way? It just download files from remote server. Internally it uses polly wrapper around http client to download files.

Comment: @cs98 the DownloadFiles method seems to be fine, at least from the signature.